# spread DataFrame column's content into a few new columns

Tags: python, pandas

My original DataFrame looks like this:

```
StudentId   DepartmentName  
1   Arts    86.677535
    Science 79.557508
2   Arts    79.542738
    Science 78.867115
3   English 83.972245
... ... ...
277 Science 81.298837
278 Science 72.578017
    Sport   76.749775
280 Arts    77.237998
    Science 75.696576
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
StudentId  Arts        Science     English     Sport
1           86.677535  79.557508    NaN        Nan
2           79.542738  78.867115    NaN        Nan
3           Nan        Nan          83.972245  Nan
... ... ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `pandas.unstack`

```
df.unstack(level=-1)
```